# How to make Popupwindow with close button in android

Tags: java, android, admob, cocos2d-x, ads

I'm making admob ads as popup window in cocos2d-x. 
It was great, but i cant find any method of add close button. so I made it.

but, Button is sticky in left top of popup window.
I want move button to right corner of popup window.

: current 
+--------+
|x          |
|           |
+--------+

: want
+--------+x
|           |
|           |
+--------+

somebody help me.

```
  _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _activity.adView.loadAd(adRequest); // google ads

            // create layout
            adLayout = new RelativeLayout(_activity);
            adLayout.setPadding(-5, -5, -5, -5);

            // create ad popup
            popUp = new PopupWindow(_activity);
            popUp.setWindowLayoutMode(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popUp.setClippingEnabled(false);
            adLayout.addView(adView);


            //close button
            ImageButton closeBtn = new ImageButton(_activity);
            closeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close);

            closeBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    _activity._hideADPopup();
                }
            });

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT); // I want send close button to right top of popup window...


            adLayout.addView(closeBtn,param2);
            popUp.setContentView(adLayout);

            mainLayout = new LinearLayout(_activity);

            MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            _activity.setContentView(mainLayout, params);

            popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            popUp.update();
        }
    });
```

Comment: try this way: `param2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);`

Comment: Make Custom layout and setview in popup window

Comment: Really Thanks, both of you.
I've tried ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT way before. but it was little strange.  
cause of background color and, not proper position of close button.
Anyway, I turn it off by popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

Comment: I think I have to try make custom layout, and setview. as Parag Chauhan. really appreciate.